# Meteor FlowRouter: replace path in history for restricted route

Tags: redirect, meteor, browser-history, flow-router

I'm using FlowRouter in a Meteor app.  In one case, a resource is not available until a certain date/time, so we redirect to another route.  Is there anyway to replace the route to the restricted resource with the path to the redirect such that the restricted resource route will not appear in the browser history. Doing will make the history (using back, forward) more UX friendly.

I can achieve this in FlowRouter's `triggersEnter` for the route, by stepping outside of FlowRouter with something like:

```
if(restricted) {
  return window.location.replace(`/waitingroom/${resourceId}/user/${Meteor.userId()}`);
}
```

...but this causes a page reload, which is sort of undesirable.

Any idears?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions pass to `triggersEnter` have the 2nd param named `redirect` you can use it to redirect to other pages without reloading the page and having a clean history:

```
FR.route('/restricted-route', {
  name: 'RestrictedRoute',
  triggersEnter: [function(context, redirect) {
    redirect('/replace-route');
  }]
});

FR.route('/replace-route', {
  name: 'ReplaceRoute',
  action() {
    // ...
  }
});
```

**Updated**

I am not sure why it's required to be sync. Anyway FlowRouter uses [Page.js](https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/) behind the scene to do navigation, if you can not use `redirect` then this should work:

```
FR.route('/restricted-route', {
  name: 'RestrictedRoute',
  triggersEnter: [function(context, redirect) {
    Meteor.setTimeout(() => {
      FlowRouter._page.replace('/replace-route');
    }, 1000);
  }]
});
```

Note: this is not the public API, therefore you should test it carefully before using in production.

Comment: The `redirect` function must synchronous, tho, and in `triggersEnter` we have an async operation, whan whan. This solution won't exactly suit my needs.

Comment: Awesome, yup, this worked, I can actually just use 0 milliseconds tho.  Thanks for the inside scoop!